# Mouse over is not changing the material when hovering over game object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to hover over certain game objects and the object changes material. I cannot figure out why my game object won't change material when I hover over it. I have made sure and added the materials in the inspector. I have tried multiple ways to get it to work but still no luck. I am using unity 2018.4.16. I have tried using different examples and looked at the documentation, but alas I am stuck in the water. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
        public Material startColor;
        public Material mouseOverColor;
        Renderer rend;

        void OnMouseOver()
        {
            rend.sharedMaterial = mouseOverColor;
        }

        void OnMouseExit()
        {
            rend.sharedMaterial = startColor;
        }

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
            rend.enabled = true;
            rend.sharedMaterial = startColor;
        }
```

Comment: What I've read from documantation is;
This function is not called on objects that belong to Ignore Raycast layer.

This function is called on Colliders marked as Trigger if and only if Physics.queriesHitTriggers is true.

So does your object have a collider ? If so is isTrigger is enabled ?

Comment: I ended up adding a Rigidbody to my game object and checking "Is Kinematic" and now it works. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I ended up having to have a mesh collider too. I thought it was just the rigidbody that made it work but I added the script to another object and it didn't work unitl I added both the rigidboday and mesh collider.

Comment: You need a collider (and possibly a rigidbody) for your script to pick up mouse related events.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a solution. I needed to add a "Rigidbody" component and then checking "Is Kinematic" in the inspector as well as adding a "mesh collider" component, and now it works for anyone who is having a similar issue.